# how to resolve this Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to build a webpage using html and nodejs . I have used ejs in some places in the html code.I am getting the following error when I run the server. Though I have added all the closing tags for every "<%" starting.

```
Error: Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
    at C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:739:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Template.generateSource (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:729:15)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:583:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\GANDHARAV\OneDrive\Desktop\nodejs\first_app\server.js:19:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

the following is my html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Comaptible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Blog Articles</h1>
        <a href="/articles/new" class="btn btn-succeess">New Article</a>

        <% articles.forEach(article = > { %>
            <div class="card mt-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><%= article.title %></h4>
                    <div class="card-subtitle tetxt-muted mb-2">
                        <%= article.createdAt.toLocalDateString() %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text mb-2"><%= article.description %></div>
                    <a href="articles/<%= article.slug %>" class="btn btn-primary"> Read more </a>
                    <a href="articles/edit/<%= article.id %>" class="btn btn-info"> Edit </a>
                    <form action="/articles/<%= article.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }) >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I have installed the following dependencies : **

```json
{
  "name": "first_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dompurify": "^2.2.6",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "marked": "^1.2.7",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.12",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "slugify": "^1.4.6"
  }
}
```

from the following picture it seems like VS code is not recognizing ejs code. Cause wherever I have started with "<%" , its showing me a red mark.

[image]

Comment: This question should be closed because it was caused by a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your `%>` closing tag is missing on the closing tags of the foreach loop, it should be `<% }) %>` you have `<% }) >`

There's also a space between the `=` and the `>` in the top of your foreach loop `<% articles.forEach(article = > { %>` which could be causing the problem. Try changing it to `<% articles.forEach(article => { %>` .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Comaptible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Blog Articles</h1>
        <a href="/articles/new" class="btn btn-succeess">New Article</a>

        <% articles.forEach(article => { %>
            <div class="card mt-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><%= article.title %></h4>
                    <div class="card-subtitle tetxt-muted mb-2">
                        <%= article.createdAt.toLocalDateString() %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text mb-2"><%= article.description %></div>
                    <a href="articles/<%= article.slug %>" class="btn btn-primary"> Read more </a>
                    <a href="articles/edit/<%= article.id %>" class="btn btn-info"> Edit </a>
                    <form action="/articles/<%= article.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```